# 'X was not found in the chain configured namespaces' in service

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a service configured in Symfony:

```
   v_bla_orm.listener.address:
        class: Bla\OrmBundle\EventListener\AddressManager
        calls:
            - [ setContainer, [ @service_container ] ]
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: prePersist } 
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: preUpdate }
```

When I run my code in a unit test the following exception will occur:

`The class 'Bla\OrmBundle\EventListener\AddressManager' was not found in the chain configured namespaces Bla\OrmBundle\Entity, Ivory\GoogleMapBundle\Entity`

When stepping through the code I determined that the exception occurs in the following line in `AddressManager`:

```
$meta = $em->getClassMetadata(get_class($entity));
```

The whole function:

```
public function preUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args) {
    $entity = $this->getLatLong($args);
    $em = $args->getEntityManager();
    $uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();
    $meta = $em->getClassMetadata(get_class($entity));
    $uow->recomputeSingleEntityChangeSet($meta, $entity);                  
}
```

What I don't understand is why should `AddressManager` be in the chain of namespaces? Since it is not an entity and when stepping step by step through the code, the code gets into the `AddressManager`?

Also how can I solve this?

**Edit**

Added lotlong function aswell

```
 public function getLatLong(LifecycleEventArgs $args) {

        $entity = $args->getEntity();

        if ($entity instanceof \Bla\OrmBundle\Entity\Address) {

            $geocoder = $this->container->get('ivory_google_map.geocoder');
            $string = $entity->getStreet() . ' ' . $entity->getStreetNumber() . ', ' . $entity->getCity() . ' ' . $entity->getCountry();
            $response = $geocoder->geocode($string);
            $results = $response->getResults();

            $entity->setLatitude(null);
            $entity->setLongitude(null);

            foreach ($results as $result) {
                $location = $result->getGeometry()->getLocation();

                $entity->setLatitude($location->getLatitude());
                $entity->setLongitude($location->getLongitude());
                return $entity;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show your `getLatLong()` method?

Comment: @Qoop Added  the function aswell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `getLatLong` is not returning an entity if it's not an instance of `\Bla\OrmBundle\Entity\Address` meaning that it is essentially return `null`.

This means that when you are later calling..

```
$meta = $em->getClassMetadata(get_class($entity));
```

.. it is really calling..

$meta = $em->getClassMetadata(get_class(null));

.. which means it will return that name of the class that called it, in this case `Bla\OrmBundle\EventListener\AddressManager`.

There are many ways to sort it but the easiest would be..

```
public function preUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args) {
    if (null === $entity = $this->getLatLong($args)) {
        return;
    }
    $em = $args->getEntityManager();
    ....                  
}
```